VBA Formula with Absolute range changes when code is executed
When I run the code below, after clearing the specific row of data the code will insert a formula with absolute references. The problem is that after a few runs of the code, the absolute references change when I look at the formula directly in the cell. Since I am not deleting these rows and then inserting the formulas I cannot figure out why those references are changing. Any insights would be appreciated.
Sub LineArchive_DD119()

    Dim TMLastDistRow
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim LastRowInRange As Long, RowCounter As Long
    
    TMLastDistRow = Worksheets("Trailer Archives").Cells(Sheet13.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LastRowInRange = Sheet11.Range("A:A").Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row ' Returns a Row Number
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Sheets("Dock Door Status").Range("P3").Value = "F" Then
        With Sheets("Dock Door Status")
            .Range("P3").Value = "F"
            .Range("C3:R3").Copy
        End With
        
        With Sheets("Trailer Archives")
            .Range("B" & TMLastDistRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear DD119?", vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "Dock Door 119 Data")
    If Answer = vbYes Then

        For RowCounter = LastRowInRange To 1 Step -1 ' Count Backwards
            If Sheet11.Range("A" & RowCounter) = Sheet22.Range("C3") Then '   If Cell matches our 'Delete if' value then
                Sheet11.Rows(RowCounter).EntireRow.Delete '       Delete the row
            End If
        Next
        
        With Sheets("Dock Door Status")
            .Range("D3:Q3").ClearContents
            .Range("D3").Formula = "=IF(E3=""RME"",""LOTO"",IF(AND(E3="""",F3<>""""),""OPEN"",""CLOSED""))"
        End With
        
        With Sheets("Dock Door Status")
            .Range("F3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!B$2:B$50,MATCH($C3,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
            '.Range("G3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!C$2:C$50,MATCH($C3,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
            '.Range("H3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!D$2:D$50,MATCH($C3,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
            .Range("I3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!E$2:E$50,MATCH($C3,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
            .Range("J3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!F$2:F$50,MATCH($C3,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
            .Range("K3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!G$2:G$50,MATCH($C3,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
            .Range("L3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!H$2:H$50,MATCH($C3,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
            .Range("M3").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!I$2:I$50,MATCH($C3,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
            .Range("Q3").Formula = "=IF(G3="""","""",IF(L3>G3,""Future"",""Current""))"
        End With
        
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub


Can you provide a specific example of the type of change you're seeing? Expected vs. Actual formula ?

It's not too clear which sheet is which - you use both the tab name and the code name in your code.  It would be cleaner to change the code name (eg Sheet13 to TrailerArch) and just use the codename in your code.

@TimWilliams One of my future projects is cleaning up the code. After a day of using the code, these are run multiple times a day, the absolute reference starts to decline i.e. "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!G$2:G$50,MATCH($C3,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$40,0)),"""")", "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!G$2:G$50,MATCH($C3,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$36,0)),"""")"

Sheet11 - SSP Data, Sheet13 - Trailer Archives, Sheet22 - Dock Door Status

Well, yes, if you delete a row from inside of a range referenced by a formula, that range reference will shrink accordingly in the formula. And it will grow if you insert rows. That's how Excel works.

@GSerg But I am not deleting rows on the sheet that the code inserts the formulas. That is the part that doesn't make sense. The rows on that sheet only get the contents cleared.

@GSerg -  After deleting the rows, the formulas are refreshed with the "original" range though?  Seems like there's something else triggering the formula changes?  Unless OP is not referring to those formulas.

@IronMan It's not important on which sheet the formulas are, it's important what they are referencing. They are referencing SSP Data which you said was Sheet11 where you delete rows from inside the range those formulas reference.

@TimWilliams You're right, but the premise still holds - the formulas change when the rows they reference are deleted. My understanding was that the OP thought that using the $absolute references prevents the formula from ever changing, which is not the case because the $ only comes to play when copying the formula from one row to another.

@GSerg OMG. That makes complete sense and can't believe I missed it. I am going to shrink into the hedges now.

This post has been tagged as a duplicate, but the two answers listed as solutions to this duplicate question did not work. Any other ideas? I already use INDEX in the code.

@GSerg So if I ask a question on SO that appears to be a duplicate, but the answers in the original questions do not work, how is closing my question helping me (or other people looking for a solution to this issue?

@IronMan It isn't, so it shouldn't be happening, and should be undone when it happens, which I can do. However, way more often than not the OP's claim that the duplicates are unhelpful is not correct :). I have looked at the duplicates and they indeed show how to compose a formula that is impervious to deletion of rows from inside of a range it references. Can you show how exactly it is not working for you?

@GSerg The first duplicate answer has an answer that I already had incorporated into my code which is using Index and absolute referencing. The second answer suggests using the OFFSET function, which I will have to look into and learn how to incorporate that into my code and test.

@IronMan I only included the OFFSET version for the sake of completeness for future readers. It is a worse solution, because OFFSET is a volatile function and INDEX is not.

@GSerg So I found that for my purposes, I can simply change the code from Delete to ClearContents where it is needed. This has made it so that the absolute references stay they way it was expected to. This solution will not work in every scenario so it is up to the developer to make the best approach.
